# Dynamics CRM Goal Métric Native Subgrid

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-2013, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2015

I have a customer that has removed a out of box subgrid from Goal Metric entity.
[image: This is the underlying Native subgrid]
Now I just wanted to add that grid again, but how?

I have tried importing that entity from another organization but it does not overwrite the entity.

I appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: Are you dealing with Managed Solutions or unmanaged?

Comment: Production enviroment I have an managed solution, in Development enviroment i have unmanaged solution

Answer (score 1):

The unmanaged solutions sit on top of the managed solutions.  So if you've allowed the client to change it, making a managed change will not fix it.  You potentially could create a workflow with a custom action that uses the SDK to put it back, but you will not be able to change it via just a solution import